# orthogonal projection proof in Conway Functional analysis book

Tags: functional-analysis

I am just trying to understand certain small thing in Conway's proof why can we construct $k_n$ such that $\|k_n\|^2 \leq d^2 + \frac{1}{4}\epsilon^2$. [image]

Comment: $\|k_n \|\to d$.

Comment: Yes, but it could approach d in any direction.

Comment: $\|k_n \|^2\to d^2$ and $d^2+\frac14\varepsilon^2>d^2$.

Comment: why is it true that $||k_n||^2 \leq d$?

Comment: @JohnB can you just add a full answer and I will accept it ?